# TypeORM getRawOne<T> not returning type T

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I'm working on refactoring a koa api to nest and am kinda stuck on refactoring the queries from native psql to typeorm. I have the following table, view and dto.

```
@Entity()
export class Challenge {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Column()
  endDate!: Date;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt!: Date;
}

@ViewEntity({
    expression: (connection: Connection) => connection.createQueryBuilder()
      .select('SUM(cp.points)', 'score')
      .addSelect('cp.challenge', 'challengeId')
      .addSelect('cp.user', 'userId')
      .addSelect('RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cp."challengeId" ORDER BY SUM(cp.points) DESC) AS rank')
      .from(ChallengePoint, 'cp')
      .groupBy('cp.challenge')
      .addGroupBy('cp.user')
})
export class ChallengeRank {
  @ViewColumn()
  score!: number;

  @ViewColumn()
  rank!: number;

  @ViewColumn()
  challenge!: Challenge;

  @ViewColumn()
  user!: User;
}

export class ChallengeResultReponseDto {
    @ApiProperty()
    id!: number;
  
    @ApiProperty()
    endDate!: Date;

    @ApiProperty()
    createdAt!: Date;
  
    @ApiProperty()
    score: number;
  
    @ApiProperty()
    rank: number;

    test() {
        console.log("test")
    }
}
```

As the object I want to return is not of any entity type, I'm kinda lost on how to select it and return the correct class. I tried the following:

```
this.challengeRepository.createQueryBuilder('c')
        .select('c.id', 'id')
        .addSelect('c.endDate', 'endDate')
        .addSelect('c.createdAt', 'createdAt')
        .addSelect('cr.score', 'score')
        .addSelect('cr.rank', 'rank')
        .leftJoin(ChallengeRank, 'cr', 'c.id = cr."challengeId" AND cr."userId" = :userId', { userId })
        .where('c.id = :id', { id })
        .getRawOne<ChallengeResultReponseDto>();
```

Which returns an object that has the correct fields, but that is not of the class type "ChallengeResultReponseDto". If I try to call the function "test" the application crashes. Further it feels weird to use the challengeRepository but not return a challenge, should I use the connection or entity manager for this instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm rather certain that `getRawOne<T>()` returns a JSON that *looks* like whatever you give the generic (T), but an not instance of that class. You should try using `getOne()` instead to get the instance of the returned entity

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. The repository is of type Repository<Challenge>. As ChallengeResultReponseDto is not an entity, I can't create a repository for it. Thus getOne would return a Challenge not a ChallengeResultReponseDto. What should I do if my response is different from my entity?

Comment: Use a maper of some sort, like `class-transformer`'s `classToClass` or `plainToClass.` If the class doesn't exist under TypeORM's metadata in the first place, there's no way it would be able to instantiate the class for you with the returned result. I do something like this for my `pg` service, making use of `plaintoClass` to transform raw JSON to a class